# IDLE (Python GUI) Does not want to open

Tags: python, python-idle

I had IDLE for both python 2.7.6 and python 3.3.3 and both worked. I didn't really mess with anything related to python but all of a sudden IDLE for python 3.3.3 stopped working. When I click on the icon in the start menu when I search IDLE my cursor indicates that something is loading for a split second but then nothing opens.

Can anyone tell me what they think the problem is?

Comment: Why don't just try to reinstall it?

Comment: Windows? You can open the command line program `cmd` with start, type cmd. Then type into the black window `C:\Python33\python.exe -m idlelib.idle`. ENTER and it will show the error message which you need to post here to get further help.

Comment: I already tried reinstalling it. When I tried that command it works but I get about a thousand warning messages that look like this. 
 Warning: configHandler.py - IdleConf.GetThemeDict -
 problem retrieving theme element 'hit-foreground'
 from theme 'Codecademy UI'.
 returning default value: '#ffffff'

Comment: So obviously it has to do with the theme modifications I did (forgot to mention that I did that), but why should it only affect python3 and not python2 and why does it still load from cmd but not from the shortcut?

Comment: In 3.3, the attempt to print the warning to a non-existent stderr (when run from shortcut) lead to an exception and Python's termination.  We have somewhat fixed that in 3.4.2 (and 2.7.8) but are not quite done yet.  As of yet, what @User said is the standard advice.